# Plotting from a created list

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib

consider the code:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in range(len(a)):

   for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
       dd21 = (a[i]-a[j])
       j = j + 1
       if i != j and dd21 !=0:
             print i, j, dd21
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.hist(dd21)
plt.tight_layout()

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

output = IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

What do I have to change my list for dd21 so that it can plot in a histogram?

Comment: dd21 isn't a list, it's -1

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is your intention to store all the `dd21` values you compute in the loop.
However, currently you overwrite `dd21` every time.

This should make it work, allowing you to plot the histogram:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
dd21 = [] # initialize empty list
for i in range(len(a)):

   for j in range(i+1, len(a)):
       dd21.append(a[i]-a[j])
       # ... continue as before
```